# Edge detection not working as expected

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, convolution

I was just playing around with convolution and kernels in SciPy and Python. I used the following kernel for edge detection since it was listed in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)):
[image: kernel]

This is the image I used:
[image: lion]

The result I got was pretty disappointing:
[image: result]

The code I used for the convolution:

```
edge = np.array([[-1, -1, -1], [-1, 8, -1], [-1, -1, -1]])
results = sg.convolve(img, edge, mode='same')
results[results > 255] = 255
results[results < 0] = 0
```

...and the code I used to read the image:

```
img = np.array(Image.open('convolution_test/1.jpg'))
img = img[:, :, 0]
```

Why am I getting these bad results?

TIA.

Comment: What is the type of the `img`. Because if it is unsiged, this might lead to underflow.

Comment: If you load the matrix as unsigned integers, then the result will probably wrap-around such that negative numbers are actually white values.

Comment: But `scipy.convolve` only works on 1d arrays?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you so much! I checked the dtype of the `img` array, and you were right... it was `uint8`. I changed it to `int32` and voila! If you write your comment as an answer, I will accept it. :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `scipy.signal.convolve` works on matrices as well. I checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that your image works with *unsigned* integers. As a result if you for instance subtract one from zero, you get `0-1 = 255` for an `uint8`, and thus you get white where the value actually should be black.

You can however easily overcome this issue by using signed integers (preferably with more depth). For instance:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sg

img = np.array(Image.open('convolution_test/1.jpg'))
img = img[:, :, 0]
img = img.astype(np.int16)

edge = np.array([[-1, -1, -1], [-1, 8, -1], [-1, -1, -1]])
results = sg.convolve(img, edge, mode='same')
results[results > 255] = 255
results[results < 0] = 0

results = results.astype(np.uint8)
```

For me this generates the following image:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Willi'a'm :p

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for the [Sobel Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator), which works fine, here is [my google colab you can run the code online](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-keL0oG5azOHxJNncJmBFAzacRgRDONB?usp=sharing)

```
from PIL import Image
#download png image which is 3D and disable the output
!wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikolalysenko/lena/master/lena.png 2>/dev/null
im = Image.open("lena.png");
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(im);
arr.shape

hx = np.array ([[1,0,-1],[2,0,-2],[1,0,-1]])
hy = np.array ([[1,2,1],[0,0,0],[-1,-2,-1]])


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import convolve
ax = arr[:, :, 0] #remove the color
Gx = convolve(ax, hx)
Gy = convolve(ax,hy)

G = np.sqrt(Gx*Gx+Gy*Gy)
plt.imshow(G, cmap='gray')
```